# Erro ao passar caminho de arquivo para fopen usando variável

Tags: c, stream-de-arquivos

Não entendo porque esse comportamento ocorre, deixo o exemplo abaixo:

```
int main (void)
{
    char caminho_do_arquivo[TAMANHO_DO_CAMINHO+1]; //TAMANHO_D0_CAMINHO Expande para 100
    FILE *arquivo_texto;

    printf("Caminho do arquivo texto: ");
    fgets(caminho_do_arquivo, TAMANHO_DO_CAMINHO, stdin); //Isso não funciona
    scanf("%s", caminho_do_arquivo); //Isso funciona

    printf("O caminho do arquivo passado foi: %s\n", caminho_do_arquivo);

    arquivo_texto = fopen(caminho_do_arquivo, "r+"); //Usando fgets isso não funciona

    //testa_abertura_arquivo retorna false em caso de erro
    if (!testa_abertura_arquivo(arquivo_texto)) 
        exit(1);
    else
        printf("Sucesso ao abrir o arquivo!\n");

    ler_arquivo(arquivo_texto);

    fclose(arquivo_texto);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que ocorre é a leitura com `fgets` porque a função está lendo o caractere de quebra de linha `\n`. Você pode [ler esta referência para mais informações](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-fgets-read-string). Já a função [`scanf`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-scanf-read-data) não lê essa quebra de linha. Você pode testar se há o caractere mencionado com a função [`strstr`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-strstr-locate-substring) (fica em `<string.h>`):

```
// você pode omitir o " != NULL" se preferir. 
if (strstr(caminho_do_arquivo, "\n") != NULL) 
    exit(1);
else
    printf("Sucesso ao abrir o arquivo!\n");
```

Com `fgets`, `strstr` vai retornar um ponteiro para a primeira ocorrência da substring passada como segundo argumento, ou seja, não será nulo (porque `\n` foi lido).

Resumindo: o arquivo não abre com `fgets` porque o caminho do seu arquivo não tem quebra de linha (`\n`).

Comment: Realmente ele estava capturando o "\n", passou despercebido, muito obrigado!

Comment: Dá pra usar fgets tranquilamente, basta substituir a quebra de linha (\n) por um caractere de final de arquivo (\0).

Comment: @BernardoLansing correto; em outras postagens aqui no SO eu cheguei a mencionar que o `scanf` tem alguns problemas quando usado dessa forma e recomendo [esta leitura](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Geralmente uso `fgets`.

Comment: @BernardoLansing inclusive fiz dessa forma logo que notei que este era o problema, me parece ser a forma mais adequada

Comment: O certo mesmo é usar a função da biblioteca getline() que já faz o gerenciamento do buffer. Você só tem que liberar o buffer no final e filtrar o '\n'. Lê strings com scanf ou fgets é meio problemático porque você não tem ideia do que vem.